# How to run Ubuntu and windows 10 on an external hard drive in a MAC?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, hard-drive, mac, boot-partition

I have a Macbook pro and a 4TB external Hard drive. Now I want to use the hard drive in a manner where I get 3 TB for random storage purposes and 500 GB for Linux and 500 GB. Now will I have to use boot camp or vm ware/virtual box and how do I do this.....please note I have dual booted linux on a windows pc before. So does anyone know how to do this or have prior experience..... as far as I have searched I found that guys can load windows 10 OR ubuntu from an external drive..... I am not certain as to how they do it but I get that it is possible........ so I want to know whether I can use a single hard drive to load BOTH windows 10 and ubuntu and still 3TB more space for my use.... if some one knows that please do advice....thanks in advance.

Comment: I would just install them in virtualbox and save the virtual disk to the external hard drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage a triple boot with your Mac. It has advantages and disadvantages:

**Advantages:**

1. You can run any Operating system with your machine.
2. You can handle with every file.(open a .exe file in windows, .run
   file on Ubuntu etc.)
3. Since it's 4 TB you have plenty space that you won't need cloud
   space and you wont need extra space for your collections.

**Disadvantages:**

1. Bootloader may be strong to configure, especially installing Windows
   will require you Bootcamp and it could be break Ubuntu's bootloader
2. You may need to plug your external HDD everytime that you open the
   machine because it might be stuck on bootloader(for not recognizing
   other OSses.)

My suggestion is that you first create a dual boot with Bootcamp. After that install Ubuntu and link them together.

You can also install without doing bootcamp that is written [here](http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required).

Good luck!